# Is the Apple Push notification service outdated?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am studying how to make push notificatons, and the common thing to use seems to be something like airpush. But I also found Apple's documentation about the Apple Push Notification Service.

That led me to wonder whether I am mixing apples and oranges, or whether the documentation for  Apple Push Notification Service is outdated.

Could anyone please clear this up.
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: APNS is the plumbing that all push notifications to iOS devices must use. Other services are third parties that make it easier for developers to do the notifying, but still use APNS as the delivery system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple Push Notification documentation is current. If you use this directly, you're responsible for building all of the backend yourself.

[Airpush](http://www.airpush.com) appears to be an advertising service, not a push notification service.

Could you perhaps be thinking of [PushIO](http://push.io/features/) instead of Airpush? PushIO is a commercial push notification service that provides the not inconsiderable infrastructure for notifications and for communication with the Apple PNS servers, as well as a bunch of analytics, location-based targeting, and many other value adds.

Comment: yes PushIO makes more sense. I am a bit confused overall. I just did the push notifications for android, and now I have to relearn the whole thing from scratch :(

Comment: I think I was thinking urbanairship :)